# Largest ellipse inside rectangle

Tags: geometry, optimization

I want to determine the largest area ellipse inscribed in a rectangle, in order to write a code that can determine the lengths *c* and *d* given *a* and *b* ([see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIK8z.png)). I know the obvious answer would be *c* and *d* are halves of *a* and *b*, but I want the derivation (and also the maximum area) so I can stop thinking about this, saddly I can't seem to figure this one out. I remember doing the opposite in school (rectangle inside ellipse) but can't do it properly now.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Scale the given rectangle, to make it a square.  Clearly the largest ellipse that fits in the square is the incircle of the square.  Now scale the square back to the original rectangle, and you have your largest ellipse.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the area of an ellipse? How are you planning to vary the ellipse inside the rectangle?

Comment: Please refer to my post concerning **Lissajous ellipse** [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838356/eliminating-theta-from-a-cos-theta-alpha-x-and-b-cos-theta-beta-y/2838863#2838863).